# How to optimize the hibernate queries.especially in inheritence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss

For hibernate optimization of queries, in Inheritence Type `Table_Per_Class`, how to avoid where clause on (union of both class) and instead on apply where clause on each subclass

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Animal {
   int pkey;
   String name;
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
   long numSlippersChewed; // int is not large enough...
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
   short miceCaught; // ... but here int is far bigger than required :-)
}
```

In the above code, if I have `subclasses` like elephant,etc,

And i make a query on Animal  of where clause on name,then
    current hibernate implementation unions all the tables, and then applies the where clause,
  which causing sql memory space issues

Can Hibernate individually apply where clause on each of the subclass and then make a union

Any pointers on this issue

Comment: hql optimize query apply where clause on each subclass